# Do a fire and forget web request using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

For a webrequest in PowerShell I use

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.it-takes-long.de' -UseBasicParsing
```

Is there a way to do a webrequest in a fire and forget way?

I call the url to warm up a web from my build server and I would rather continue to the next step and not wait for the web to start up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just put the invoke into a **job** using the `Start-Job` cmdlet:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.it-takes-long.de' -UseBasicParsing}
```

Comment: Having the correct answer in 20s and the question improved in 1min thats a new record. I did not even know that I have to wait some time (12min) until I can accept an answer.

Comment: that's pretty common in Powershell tag, not a lot of questions, a lot of people monitoring @MathiasF

Comment: Also your question was nice and clean, not much uncessary stuff to read ;-). You are welcome

Comment: If you want to use a variable as the url, make sure to define the parameter in the script block and pass it as an argument. That tripped me up for a bit.

```Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($url) Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing} -ArgumentList $url```